How to solve this minesweeper board
How would you resolve this board?

The game is generated by AI at the website mineswifter.com and is a solvable game.
This picture is the board, in yellow is a clue provided by the web page. But it does not tell me if it is a number or a bomb.
There are 5 bombs resting. I do not know why is  there a clue at the indicated yellow block. Is there any way to determine if the yellow block is a bomb or a number?
How would you know where are the bombs within the 2x2 block?

I'm going to start downvoting these minesweeper questions, since they are extremely specific to your in-game situation and will not be useful to anybody else. To quote the tool-tip: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

Is it perhaps time to revisit How should we handle questions asking how to solve a specific Minesweeper board?

@TimmyJim As a note (not disagreeing), this is the only user to post minesweeper questions recently.

The puzzling.se site may be more welcoming to such a question but preferably there should be something interesting about the specific situation, not just a generic 'solve this minesweeper'.

Yes - It's solvable.
Try looking at the board again. There are two tiles that you can use to determine that yellow tile.
Solution:

 The yellow square is clean.

 

 You've already figured out two of the three bombs for that three, so the last bomb is in one of the three squares marked in green.
 However, for that 2 bomb clue, the yellow square does not overlap with the green squares and because a bomb MUST be in one of the green squares, it can't be on the yellow square otherwise it would break the clue.

 

 The final five squares aren't solvable without more clues or knowing how many are bombs left.


Using the knowledge that there are five hidden bombs total, we can actually place one more. The remaining two must be adjacent to the 4 cell, which means that the top row is empty, pinning one of those mines to rightmost cell of the second row.

That's correct, I did find it too, but I couldn't be bothered to edit the answer :P
